# TypeScript ignoring type of const. Why does this compile?

Tags: typescript, tsc

In certain cases I set the type of a `const`, and TypeScript ignores it.  In particular, sometimes I add `| undefined` and TypeScript ignores the fact that the value might be undefined.  Am I missing something?

I'm grabbing an element from an `Array` or a `NodeList`.  I'm saving it in a `let` or a `const`.  By default TypeScript assumes that an array access will never fail.  I know this particular array access is very likely to fail.  I'm trying to mark the type of the expression so when I try to use it later I don't forget to check for `undefined`.  Here's an example:

```
const myArray = ["a", "b", "see", "d", "e", "f"];

// Default:
export const plain0 = myArray[0];    // "a"
export const plain9 = myArray[9];    // undefined
export const plainMissing = undefined; // undefined

console.log(plain0.length);  // This will work as expected.
console.log(plain9.length);  // This will cause a runtime error.
console.log(plainMissing.length);  // Does not compile.

// With explicitly variable declarations:
export const variableType0 : string | undefined = myArray[0];
export const variableType9 : string | undefined = myArray[9];
export const variableTypeMissing : string | undefined = undefined; // undefined

console.log(variableType0.length);  // Compiles but shouldn't!!!!
console.log(variableType9.length);  // Compiles but shouldn't!!!!
console.log(variableTypeMissing.length);  // Does not compile!
```

VS Code and `tsc` agree on the results.  They both ignore my type declarations and allow me to access a `string | undefined` as if it was a `string`.  The compiler is ignoring my declarations.  It's treating `variableType`* in my code just like `plain`*.

I asked `tsc` to generate a `.d.ts` file for me.  That confirms that it knows the second set of constants should have different types than the first set.

```
export declare const plain0: string;
export declare const plain9: string;
export declare const plainMissing: undefined;
export declare const variableType0: string | undefined;
export declare const variableType9: string | undefined;
export declare const variableTypeMissing: string | undefined;
```

When I'm in VS Code and I hover my mouse over any of the `const` statements, the tool tips show me the same types as the `.d.ts` files.  These are the values I'm expecting.

But when I hover my mouse over any of the `log` statements, I see different types.  On those lines, the tool tips for `variableType0`,  `variableType9`, and `variableTypeMissing` are `string`, `string`, and `undefined`, respectively.  Those types perfectly match the errors that I see.  But those types do **not** match their declarations.

Is there some reason that TypeScript is ignoring my declarations?  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Am I misunderstanding the rules?  Is it a bug in the compiler?  **How can I mark the code so the compiler will force me to use `?.` not just `.`?**

This is my tsconfig.json.  It mostly comes from vite, but I changed a few things.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./types",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**EDIT / Simpler Example**

```
const x : number|undefined = Math.random();
x.toFixed();

const y : number|string = Math.random();
y.toFixed();
```

This version does not use arrays.
I'm running into the same problem.
TypeScript thinks it knows the type of the variable.
I'm telling TypeScript that I know better by offering a declaration.
TypeScript is **not** giving me an error, saying it doesn't like my declaration.
But then it ignores my declaration.

Comment: You want to set to `true` the compiler option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) (which, unfortunately, doesn't come along with some other checks by default when just using `"strict": true`). Here's [your code in a TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbB94m) with that feature enabled.

Comment: There are quite a few things going on here which maybe makes this question too broad, or at least means I need to inquire about which of these issues is the crux of your question.  One: the compiler has no idea which values are at which index of `myArray`, because it is inferred as just `string[]`.  If you use a `const` assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAK3Rw) then the compiler knows more and will get more upset if you index outside the array.

Comment: Two: if you do not want to write `as const`... by default, TypeScript assumes indexing into a type with an index signature will always be defined.  This is not safe, but it allows certain idiomatic JS (like `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { arr[i] }`).  If you want the compiler to understand that indexing into a `string[]` should give you `string | undefined`, then you need to enable `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3P8jW), but then the compiler will always, always complain.  Most people hate that, so it's not enabled by default with `--strict`.

Comment: Three: either way, the compiler uses control flow analysis to narrow the apparent type of a union-typed variable to some of its constituents upon [assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments).  `let a: string | undefined = "hello";` will let you immediately write `a.toUpperCase()`, because the type of `a` has been narrowed to `string` by the assignment, and will stay narrowed until/unless you reassign it.  It is therefore not true that annotating as `string | undefined` should behave the way you claim.

Comment: Which of those are the main issue for you?  If I write up an answer with all three it will be ten pages long.  Could you [edit] the question to make it clear what the primary issue is, possibly by removing code that isn't directly related to that issue?  It's possible you might want to split this into multiple question posts.  Let me know.

Comment: I understand that `noUncheckedIndexedAcces` is false by default.  I agree that is a good default.  I know that `plain0`, `plain9`, and `plainMissing` are working as designed.  I included those only for comparison.

Comment: But in a few specific cases I explicitly told it the variable has a different type than it thinks.  Specifically `string | undefined`.  And it ignored those declarations!  Why is it ignoring those declarations?

Comment: "the compiler has no idea which values are at which index of myArray, because it is inferred as just string[]. If you use a const assertion".  `as const` will *not* help.  I only created that array to create a very simple example.  The original problem was reading a `string[]` from the result of a function.  In that case the compiler has no way to know the length of the array.

Comment: You: "But in a few specific cases I explicitly told it the variable has a different type than it thinks. Specifically `string | undefined`. And it ignored those declarations! Why is it ignoring those declarations?" Me, before: "the compiler uses control flow analysis to narrow the apparent type of a union-typed variable to some of its constituents upon [assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your simplified example:

```
const x : number|undefined = Math.random();
x.toFixed();
```

TypeScript can sometimes [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent type of a variable/property/expression.

In particular, when a variable is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (like `number | undefined`), the compiler will narrow the apparent type of that variable upon **[assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments)** to just those union members compatible with the value being assined.  Since `Math.random()` is of type `number`, the assignment `x = Math.random()` will narrow the apparent type of `x` from `number | undefined` to `number`.

This is generally seen as desirable behavior; without narrowing you would never be able to type guard values; a check like `if (x !== undefined) x.toFixed()` would not work because the check `x !== undefined` would have no bearing on the apparent type of `x`.  Without assignment narrowing, `if (x !== undefined) x = 5;` followed by `x.toFixed()` would be an error.

In any case, if you don't like this behavior, the only way to fix it is to make sure the value being assigned is widened to the full union type before the assignment.  The easiest way to do this is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on this value. The expression `Math.random() as number | undefined` is of type `number | undefined`, so if you assign that to `x` you will get no narrowing:

```
const y = Math.random() as number | undefined;
y.toFixed(); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhmArgWwEYFMBOMA+MKYAJlgGYCWYWJMAvDALICGUAFgHQ4ukhoAKAJQBuAFBxOUEADFKcWsJEwA9CpggA1iwCeYsaEiwdDZmy48+goTBYRk6bHkLEyVGiXE6ps+YtGq6rg4IDhAA)

Comment: Thanks.  I know that rule for `let`.  But it never occurred to me that that same thing was happening with my `const`s.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
export const expressionType0 = myArray[0] as string | undefined;
export const expressionType9 = myArray[9] as string | undefined;

console.log(expressionType0.length);  // Does not compile!
console.log(expressionType9.length);  // Does not compile!
```

This does what I want.  It tells TypeScript to ignore its normal rules.  Just in these two cases array indexes must be checked.  VS Code even suggested that I replace the `.` with a `?.`.

**I still wish I understood why my first attempt failed.**  Casting the expression worked exactly as I wanted.  But casting the variable did not.